# How to automaticly place file name for a link in php

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am wanting to pull a name from a database using php and place it in a link. For example:

```
echo" -td- -a href ='**$EmployeeID**.jpg'>View Form /a-";
```

`$EmployeeID` being the name of the file i am wanting to place in the link. My issues is adding the file extension (.jpg) on the end of it. Is this possible?

Comment: how did u get upvotes for a simple question about string concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$EmployeeID` is the name of the file, you can add .jpg at the end of it thanks to this line:

```
$EmployeeId = $EmployeeID.'.jpg';
```

So after your edit, your echo will be:

```
echo ' -td- -a href ="'.$EmployeeID.'.jpg">View Form /a-';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!!!! That was exactly what I needed. I knew it was something simple that I was missing.